# Assigning LAN TLD's

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, bind, local-area-network

Let's say that I am setting up an experiment of sorts with two or more DNS servers. These DNS servers will handle DNS requests for `<domain>.lan` tlds.

Let's say that `dns.lan` points to the first DNS server.

Now, with one DNS server holding all TLD records and their respective subdomains records, everything works well.

***Know That***

- *The **First** server will forward unmet requests out to global DNS*
- *The **Second** server will forward unmet requests to the **First** server*

However, should I want to have a different server handle DNS for a certain domain like `webstage.lan`, and I set up the first DNS server with an NS record to point to the second server in order to do so, I run in to errors:

- If I query the **first** server for `webstage.lan`, I get a response like `Can not find webstage.lan: No Answer`

  - If I query the **first** server for `dns.lan` (a domain handled entirely by the **first** server), I get a satisfactory response.
- If I query the **second** server (the server acting as a nameserver for `webstage.lan`) for `dns.lan` (a domain handled entirely by the **first** server) I get an `NXDOMAIN` response.

  - If I query the **second** server for the domain `webstage.lan` (the domain handled by the **second** server), I get a satisfactory response

How can I configure this so that queries for `webstage.lan` made to the **first** server will reflect the information on the **second** server, and that queries made on the **second** server for information on other servers or the **first** server (`dns.lan`) will be filled properly?

### Configurations:

**First Server:** [Relevant Configuration Files](http://pastebin.com/GiH1Jg3m)

**Second Server:** [Relevant Configuration Files](http://pastebin.com/Lcyhwq6g)

### Reading:

***Supplemental Information***

- *Reverse DNS is behaving in the same manner*
- *Tests performed both at the server and at a client encounter the same errors*
- *The machines have `hostname`'s corresponding to their assigned domains*
- *`<domain>.local` (mDNS) domains are not employed in this configuration*

***Know That***

- *The IP address of the **First** DNS server is:* 10.10.10.99
- *The IP address of the **Second** DNS server is:* 10.10.10.67

### ***Solution***

I fixed my own problem.

I configured the **First** to handle `webstage.lan` as a slave zone cloned from my **Second** server.

Comment: `The Second server will forward unmet requests to the First server`.  So you have configured that first server to be a single point of failure?

Comment: The second server is an HTTP server, too, and is configured in the same manner that one would configure a VPS (for instance) to provide access via a registered domain name. If that's what you are asking about.


    `Client needs IP for webstage.local` -> **First server** <- NS is **Second Server** -> ...

Comment: Don't use made up TLDs like `.lan` please.

Comment: None of this is used in a real network implementation. This is/was part of a closed network lab.